# Bash executing command

Tags: bash, sh

Can anyone please give me the list generated by this :

```
-{ for i in {1..100}; do lynx -dump -nonumbers -listonly [http]://www.dailymotion.com/user/MTDCafe/$i [http]://www.dailymotion.com/visited/user/MTDCafe/$i http://www.dailymotion.com/rated/user/MTDCafe/$i; echo $i 1>&2; done } |grep http://www.dailymotion.com/video/ |sort |uniq >movies.txt-
```

I have no idea what is Bash and stuff... all I want is the complete list of video urls of this dailymotion channel, and i found this script on the internet so i changed the channel name... and now i don't know how to execute this !

thank you for your help :)

Comment: sorry but I think nobody should run code posted by a stranger on their machine - even more as you say you don't know what it does. If you are unfamiliar with sh then select a different tool. I just had a look at this url and it's just 4 pages so even copy and paste are visble solutions.

Answer (score 0):

To execute a bash script issue 'chmod +x xxx.sh' where xxx.sh is your script filename, then issue 'sh xxx.sh'.
That should do the work for you...

Comment: If you issue the command sh xxx.sh you do not have to have execute access only read access is needed.

Comment: i realy appreciate your answer but i have no idea what this is all about :/ 
can you please please please dump the list for me ?